# Are these moments estimators asymptotic unbiased?

Tags: inference, unbiased-estimator, method-of-moments

In this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02664763.2021.1940109?journalCode=cjas20), authors consider method of moments of fitting Gumbel distribution:

We know that maximal likelihood estimators are asymptotic unbiased. But are these moments estimators asymptotic unbiased? Or consistent estimators?

Can we find the reference to say these two estimators are asymptotic normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the Gumbell distribution has finite moments. As a result, the law of large numbers implies that
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset p\to \mathbb E[X],\quad \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \overset p\to \mathbb E[X^2]$$
Moreover, the CLT implies that
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mathbb E[X] \\ \frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \mathbb E[X^2]\end{pmatrix} \overset d\to \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$$
where
$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{Var}(X) & \mathrm{Cov}(X,X^2)\\ \mathrm{Cov}(X,X^2) & \mathrm{Var}(X^2)\end{pmatrix}$$
Given this information, we are ready to calculate the asymptotic distributions of $\hat\mu$ and $\hat \sigma$. First, let us calculate the probability limit of $s$. We have that
$$s = \sqrt{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2} \equiv f\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2, \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$$
where by definition, the function $f$ is $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x - y^2}$. Note that $f$ is a continuous function of its arguments so by the continuous mapping theorem, we have that
$$s = \sqrt{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2} \overset p\to \sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2} = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)} = \pi \sigma / \sqrt 6$$
But this implies that
$$\hat\sigma = \frac{s\sqrt 6}{\pi}\overset p\to \pi \sigma / \sqrt 6\times \sqrt 6 / \pi = \sigma$$
By similar reasoning, we know that
$$\hat\mu \overset p\to \mathbb E[X] - \gamma\sigma = \mu + \gamma\sigma - \gamma\sigma = \mu$$

This shows that $\hat \mu,\hat\sigma$ are consistent. Next, we can apply [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to show asymptotic normality of $\hat\mu,\hat\sigma$. Specifically, we note that we can represent
$$\begin{pmatrix}\hat\mu\\\hat\sigma\end{pmatrix} = G\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)$$
where $G$ is a nice and differentiable function of its arguments. The delta method thus shows that
$$\sqrt n\left[\begin{pmatrix}\hat\mu\\\hat\sigma\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}\mu\\\sigma\end{pmatrix}\right]\overset d\to \mathcal N(0,\nabla G(\mathbb E[X],\mathbb E[X^2])^T\Sigma\nabla G(\mathbb E[X],\mathbb E[X^2]))$$
This last result shows asymptotic normality and asymptotic unbiasedness of $(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma)$. I will leave it to you to specify what $G$ is and to derive what the resulting asymptotic variance of $(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are.

Equation 4 in the paper says
$$E[X]=\mu+\gamma\sigma$$
and
$$\mathrm{var}[X]= \pi^2\sigma^2/6$$
and rearranging these gives the formulas for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as functions of the true moments

The sample moments are consistent for the true moments, so these smooth functions of the sample moments are consistent for the same functions of the true moments

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused. Can we prove that? Or they are moreover the unbiased estimator? It seems that we need $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Consistency of the moments follows from the law of large numbers.

Comment: So you mean as $n\to \infty$, $\hat{\sigma}^2\to^{a.s.} \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sigma^2$ by strong law of large number. This estimator is strong consistency. But for $\hat{\mu}$, it seems that as $n\to \infty$, $\hat{\mu}\to^{a.s.} \mu-\gamma \sigma$? This is not equal to $\mu$?

Comment: @Hermi how do you compute $\hat{\mu}$ as $\hat{\mu} = \bar{X}$, or as $\hat{\mu} = \bar{X} - \gamma \hat{\sigma}$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus So Is $\hat{\sigma}$ a consistent estimators? It seems that no, right? Because $\hat{\sigma}^2\to \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sigma^2\neq \sigma^2$?

Comment: Can we find the reference to say these two estimators are asymptotic normal?

Comment: @Hermi in the method of moments $\hat{\sigma}$ does not need to equal the sample deviation. You have $S_n^2 \to \text{var}[X]$, and this $V_X = \text{var}[X]$ is how you parameterize the distribution instead of the scale parameter $\sigma$. You can compute the estimate for $\sigma$ with the estimate for $V_x$. $$\hat{\sigma} = \frac{\sqrt{6 \hat{V}_x}}{\pi} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\pi} S_n$$

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I mean how to prove that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is consistent estimator?

Comment: @Hermi The (uncorrected) sample variance can be written in terms of the difference between two terms $A_n$ and $B_n$ each of which will approach the population mean of the respective variables $X^2$ and $X$ by the law of large numbers $$S^2 = \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)}_{A_n} -{ \underbrace{ \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)}_{B_n}}^2$$